# How do I select the name in dropdown using javascript?

Tags: javascript, select

I've tried using these. Using getElementById it works for a dropdown with id. But when change to getElementsByName for a dropdown without an id, it doesn't.

```js
var name = "Charlie";
function setSelectedIndex(s, v) {
    for ( var i = 0; i < s.options.length; i++ ) {
        if ( s.options[i].text.slice(0,name.length) == v ) {
            s.options[i].selected = true;
            return;
        }
    }
}
setSelectedIndex(document.getElementsByName('attributes[10]'),name);
```

```html
<select name="attributes[10]" title="Football Player" class="attribute_selected attribute_required">
  <option value="">Select name</option>
  <option value="" selected="selected"></option>
  <option value="159" >David</option>
  <option value="163" >Charlie</option>
  <option value="407" >Chris</option>
  <option value="161" >Ramon</option>
  <option value="356" >John</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

getElementsByName return array but getElementById return DOM Object.

[getElementsByName](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByName)

[getElementById](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById)

Answer (score 0):

You notice the `s` in `getElementsByName`, it hints that it returns a collection on elements not just a single one. To get access to elements in this collection you can use array notation `collection[index]`.
So  in your code

```js
var name = "Charlie";
function setSelectedIndex(s, v) {
    for ( var i = 0; i < s.options.length; i++ ) {
        if ( s.options[i].text.slice(0,name.length) == v ) {
            s.options[i].selected = true;
            return;
        }
    }
}
setSelectedIndex(document.getElementsByName('attributes[10]')[0],name);
```

```html
<select name="attributes[10]" title="Football Player" class="attribute_selected attribute_required">
  <option value="">Select name</option>
  <option value="" selected="selected"></option>
  <option value="159" >David</option>
  <option value="163" >Charlie</option>
  <option value="407" >Chris</option>
  <option value="161" >Ramon</option>
  <option value="356" >John</option>
</select>
```